# Mapping groupby mean statistics as a new column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I am having a problem mapping groupby mean statistics to a dataframe column in order to produce a new column.

The raw data is as follows:

[image]

I set about creating a new data frame which would display the average sales for 2018 by 'Brand Origin'.

[image]

I then proceeded to convert the new data frame to a dictionary in order to complete the mapping process.
I attempted to map the data to the original data frame but I get NaN values.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `transform`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Brand Origin')['2018'].transform('mean')
```